# Chrome crashes on .html()/.append()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

When I try to replace the html of an element with `$('#myDiv').html(s)`, Chrome crashes. It works in Firefox. Chrome tries to load ("waiting for localhost" or "waiting for extension AdBlock" or forever loading jQuery...) until it says the page has crashed. Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Further, if I don't alter the HTML from within the function, but instead use the console, it works!

```
function genTables(rows, numItems) {
    var cols = parseInt(numItems / rows) + 1;
    s = '<table><tbody>';
    for (i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
            s += '<tr><td>foo</td></tr>';
        }
        if ((i + 1) != cols) {
            s += '</tbody></table><table><tbody>';
        }
    };
    s += '</tbody></table><div class="clear"></div>';
    $('#myTables').html(s);
    // This crashes Chrome as well 
    //$('#myTables').append($.parseHTML(s));
}
```

Comment: Please disable all extensions before asking a browser-specific question.

Comment: Also, note that you are making three global variables -- `s`, `i`, and `j`.

Comment: It still crashes in Incognito, with no extensions.

Comment: would you be able to post a jsfiddle that replicates the issue?

Comment: Does not crash Chrome 38. @Totò, here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0x8wtsps/).

Comment: hmm that jsFiddle is not crashing for me either. Could it have to do with running on localhost?? I don't see why it would.

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle. It doesn't crash on Chrome 36 either, the issue may be related to a specific version

Comment: It must have something to do with the rest of the code...even though commenting that one line out prevents the crash. Copying the jsFiddle into a local HTML file did not crash Chrome. Anyways thanks for the help.

Comment: It looks like it never adds a final </tbody></table>.

Comment: @MelindaWeathers true, but I just forgot to add that to the question. That's in my code. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, and facepalm.

Later in my function I had a while loop:

```
while (newDiff > 0) {
    $('#myTables table.hasPad').each(function() {
        if (newDiff > 0) {
            $(this).find('tr td:first-child').each(function() {
                var currPad = parseInt($(this).css('padding-left').slice(0, -2));
                $(this).css({'padding-left' : currPad + 1 + 'px'});
                console.log(currPad + ' -> ' + (currPad + 1));
            });
            newDiff -= 1;
        }
    }
}
```

This loop would run forever since no

```
$('#myTables table.hasPad')
```

elements exist.Switch the 9th line of my function for

```
s += '</tbody></table><table class="hasPad"><tbody>';
```

and it all works. Yet, this leads me to wonder, why did it work in Firefox?